# Delete rows from one sheet based on values from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have total email ids in COL A of Sheet 1 and bounced email ids in COL A of Sheet 2.  I want to delete Sheet 1 values or entire rows based on values on Sheet 2.

I tried the following code but doesn't work.

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()

'look at sheet2, A1 through A3 for search values
For Each search_value In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3")
'as long as there is something to delete...
  Do While Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3"). _
    Find(search_value.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    '...delete that row
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3").Find(search_value.Value, _
    lookat:=xlWhole).EntireRow.Delete
  Loop
Next

End Sub
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws1
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("B1:B" & lrow)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(MATCH(A1," & ws2.Name & "!A:A,0),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this one:

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngToDel As Range, c As Range
    Dim lastRow as Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row  
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    End With

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

    For Each c In rng1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
            'if value from rng1 is found in rng2 then remember this cell for deleting
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = c
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Still it is not deleting from Sheet 1.

Comment: are you sure your values indeed equals? code works for me perfectly..check your values for additional leading/trailing spaces

Comment: There are no leading or trailing spaces. The values exactly match. But still it is not deleting in Sheet 1.

Comment: ah, Simoco, I think rng1 and rng2 are mixed up. It should be searching for the values from Sheet2 in Sheet1, so the for each should be on rng2 and the .Match on rng1. Best approach otherwise imo and should run fast. @Paramasivan imo a comment like "It is not working" does not really help without providing more information e.g. stepping through the code in debug mode and describing what was/was not happening.